# Install Google Settings on HAXM x86 emulator (Google Maps SDK)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I've gotten a VM accelerated Android emulator (4.2.2, API 17) working using Intel HAXM (on a Mac). I installed the Google Maps SDK using [these instructions](http://codebutler.com/2012/10/10/configuring-a-usable-android-emulator/), which is basically [this answer to a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540106/1282635) - Google maps SDK with new Intel Atom x86 emulator - but with pictures.

Therefore, the emulator has access to Google APIs. However, I need to enable location access for Google apps. This is usually done through the [Google Settings app](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3446972/how-enable-google-apps-location-access/), but since the emulator was created targeted to API 17 (not Google APIs 17), Maps and Google Settings are not installed.

Where can I find the .apk for Google Settings in order to install it? It would be even better if there was a way to permanently keep it on the emulator (so that -wipe-data does not delete it).

(I know I need to enable location access because of a problem I was running into earlier. See my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262190/1282635).)

Comment: have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator

Comment: @RohanKandwal Ah, I didn't, thanks! The other answers seem to confirm that Google Apps/Google Play must be installed. I switched to Genymotion, which also doesn't have Google API support, but you can install it using [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu/20013322#20013322).

Comment: Then either i should provide an answer or you should provide the method you used and then mark the question solved. Should i do it or u?

Comment: @RohanKandwal Please answer (since my method is a workaround). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a [new x86 system image available](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/06/now-available-android-sdk-x86-system-image-with-google-apis) which has the Google APIs. Install it from the SDK manager - it's under API 19 and called "Google APIs (x86 System Image)". Using an emulator created from that image you should find you have all the Google APIs you could previously only get on ARM system images (I have only tested Maps v2 so far, but it worked).

Comment: Updated this as the accepted answer, since times have changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per `Google Android Map Api v2` ypu can't run it on an `Android Emulator`; you need a real device to test your apps. To run a app which uses Google Maps v2 you need two applications already running on the device

```
1. Google Play Services (com.google.android.gms.apk)
2. Google Play Store (com.android.vending.apk)
```

[Follow this guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869332/1979347) to download and install the latest version of these two apk's using `adb commands`.