# Can we execute google map without HAXM?

Tags: android, google-maps

Can we execute Google map v2 without installing HAXM? Because whenever  tried to execute my application  its shows emulator: Failed to open the HAX device and also it shows compatibility issues. I installed Intel (X86)emulator accelerator in SDK manager but couldn't view Google map. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't view Google Gaps in the emulator because emulators don't have `google-play-service` library installed on them. So basically the best option for you would be to test you application on a real device.

You could try to install the `google-play-service` manually, but this is a lot of work and not really worth it. Not long ago you had a `Genymotion` emulator you could use that came with `google-play-service` integrated. But now they removed this support and you should install it manually there to.

You could check this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 on the Emulator](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)

But the files provided there are not relevant today, as new versions of `google-play-service` came out since then. You will need to get new apk files to install.

Answer (score 1):

The Google API's will NOT work with HAXM Emulators.  This is because the HAXM drivers from Intel don't include support for this.

If you would like to create an emulator that makes use of the Google APIs (like Maps, or GCM), you will have to create a normal emulator (not one using HAXM).

This is a good SO answer, which has a link to how to install Google APIs, on a HAXM emulator, and other good info about your situation:  [Install Google Settings on HAXM x86 emulator (Google Maps SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263054/install-google-settings-on-haxm-x86-emulator-google-maps-sdk)